# How do I filter out PFObjects from my query based on their PFUser field

Tags: ios, macos, parse-platform

I have a Parse class called `Sessions` with a bunch of different fields, one of which is called `user`. This field is of type `PFUser`.

In my OS X app, I have a simple query that pulls particular sessions in a date range, but it's currently including sessions from my test accounts. No good!

How do I filter out sessions where the `user` field matches one of these test accounts? (Specifically, the `name` field of the corresponding `PFUser`.)

Answer (score 1):

Using relational queries! It's actually really easy:

```
let innerQuery=PFUser.query()!
innerQuery.whereKey("username", notContainedIn:["TestAccount1","TestAccount2"]) 
let query = PFQuery(className: "Session");
query.whereKey("user", matchesQuery:innerQuery)
// Add in normal query conditions here
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { 
    ...
}
```

Note that this also has the (in my case, desired) effect of omitting any sessions where the `user` field doesn't match any users at all. So, any sessions corresponding to deleted user accounts won't be returned.

For more information and examples, look under the Relational Queries heading [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries).